# Compare two array of objects with matching key and value pair with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two array of objects with different key/value pair. I want to match these if it doesnt match then console log the unmatched object.

```
array1=[
{'mobile': '24pp'},
{'android': '30pp'},
{ 'ios': '23pp'}
]

array2=[
{'ios': '23pp'},
{'android': '30pp'},
{'mobile': '24pp'}
]
```

If we try to compare array1 and array2, it should return true

```
array3=[
{'ios': '23pp'},
{'android': '30pp'},
{'mobile': '30pp'}
]
```

If we try to compare array1 and array3, it should return false and return `{mobile: '24pp'}`

Here is my code example  but it compares objects one to one but in my case it can be in any order.

```js
const array1 = [{
    'mobile': '24pp'
  },
  {
    'android': '30pp'
  },
  {
    'ios': '23pp'
  }
]

const array2 = [{
    'ios': '23pp'
  },
  {
    'android': '30pp'
  },
  {
    'mobile': '24pp'
  }
]

const array3 = [{
    'ios': '23pp'
  },
  {
    'android': '30pp'
  },
  {
    'mobile': '30pp'
  }
]

function objectsMatch(obj1, obj2) {
  const keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
  const keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);

  if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  // Iterate through the keys and compare their values
  for (const key of keys1) {
    if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // If all key-value pairs match, return true
  return true;
}


for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  console.log('matched ' + objectsMatch(array1[i], array2[i]));

}
```

Comment: Objects with dynamic keys are difficult to work with. Can you change them to something like `{platform: 'ios', value: '24pp'}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compare the corresponding indexes. For each object in one array, use `some()` to check if a matching object exists in the other array.

Use `every()` to test if all elements in the array have a match in the other array.

```js
function objectsMatch(obj1, obj2) {
  const keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
  const keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);

  if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  // Iterate through the keys and compare their values
  for (const key of keys1) {
    if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // If all key-value pairs match, return true
  return true;
}

function compareArrays(a1, a2) {
  if (a1.length != a2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  return a1.every(el1 => {
    return a2.some(el2 => objectsMatch(el1, el2));
  });
}

const array1 = [{
    'mobile': '24pp'
  },
  {
    'android': '30pp'
  },
  {
    'ios': '23pp'
  }
]

const array2 = [{
    'ios': '23pp'
  },
  {
    'android': '30pp'
  },
  {
    'mobile': '24pp'
  }
]

const array3 = [{
    'ios': '23pp'
  },
  {
    'android': '30pp'
  },
  {
    'mobile': '30pp'
  }
]

console.log("Compare array1 and array2");
console.log(compareArrays(array1, array2));
console.log("Compare array1 and array3");
console.log(compareArrays(array1, array3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the length of the keys. If they are the same, you should then check every other object. This works for *n*-number of items.

**Note:** After the keys are determined to be the same length, you need to transform the sub-array of objects into one object.

```js
const data = [
  [{ 'android' : '30pp' }, { 'ios'     : '23pp' }, { 'mobile'  : '24pp' }],
  [{ 'android' : '30pp' }, { 'mobile'  : '24pp' }, { 'ios'     : '23pp' }],
  [{ 'ios'     : '23pp' }, { 'android' : '30pp' }, { 'mobile'  : '24pp' }],
  [{ 'ios'     : '23pp' }, { 'mobile'  : '24pp' }, { 'android' : '30pp' }],
  [{ 'mobile'  : '24pp' }, { 'android' : '30pp' }, { 'ios'     : '23pp' }],
  [{ 'mobile'  : '24pp' }, { 'ios'     : '23pp' }, { 'android' : '30pp' }]
];

const areAllEqual = (...items) => {
  if (items.length < 2) return false;
  const [keys, ...otherKeys] = items.map(arr =>
    [...arr.reduce((set, obj) => set.add(...Object.keys(obj)), new Set)]);
  if (otherKeys.some((other) => other.length !== keys.length)) return false;
  const [obj, ...otherObjs] = items.map(arr => Object.assign({}, ...arr));
  return otherObjs.every(otherObj =>
    keys.every(key => otherObj[key] === obj[key]));
}

console.log('Are all equal?', areAllEqual(...data)); // Verify all permutations
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the arrays have the same keys just make an object from the first array and loop the second and check whether a value with the same key in the object is the same:

```js
const compare = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const map = {};
  for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    for(const k in arr1[i]){
      map[k] = arr1[i][k];
    }
  }
  for(let i=0;i < arr2.length;i++){
    const item = arr2[i];
    for(const k in item){
      if(map[k] !== item[k]){
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
console.log('array1 === array2 : ' , compare(array1, array2));
console.log('array1 === array3 : ' , compare(array1, array3));
```

```html
<script>
const array1=[
{'mobile': '24pp'},
{'android': '30pp'},
{ 'ios': '23pp'}
]

const array2=[
{'ios': '23pp'},
{'android': '30pp'},
{'mobile': '24pp'}
]
const array3 = [{
    'ios': '23pp'
  },
  {
    'android': '30pp'
  },
  {
    'mobile': '30pp'
  }
]
</script>
```

And a benchmark with 10 items:

[image: ![enter image description here]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="500000">

const array1=[
{'mobile': '24pp'},
{'android': '30pp'},
{ 'ios': '23pp'},
{'1thing1' : '20pp'},
{'2thing2' : '20pp'},
{'3thing3' : '20pp'},
{'4thing4' : '20pp'},
{'5thing5' : '20pp'},
{'6thing6' : '20pp'},
{'7thing7' : '20pp'},

]

const array2=[
{'ios': '23pp'},
{'android': '30pp'},
{'mobile': '24pp'},
{'1thing1' : '20pp'},
{'2thing2' : '20pp'},
{'3thing3' : '20pp'},
{'4thing4' : '20pp'},
{'5thing5' : '20pp'},
{'6thing6' : '20pp'},
{'7thing7' : '20pp'},
]
const array3 = [
{'1thing1' : '20pp'},
{'2thing2' : '20pp'},
{'3thing3' : '20pp'},
{'4thing4' : '20pp'},
{'5thing5' : '20pp'},
{'6thing6' : '20pp'},
{'7thing7' : '20pp'},
{
    'ios': '23pp'
  },
  {
    'android': '30pp'
  },
  {
    'mobile': '30pp'
  }
]

// @benchmark Polywhirl

const areAllEqual = (...items) => {
  if (items.length < 2) return false;
  const [keys, ...otherKeys] = items.map(arr =>
    [...arr.reduce((set, obj) => set.add(...Object.keys(obj)), new Set)]);
  if (otherKeys.some((other) => other.length !== keys.length)) return false;
  const [obj, ...otherObjs] = items.map(arr => Object.assign({}, ...arr));
  return otherObjs.every(otherObj =>
    keys.every(key => otherObj[key] === obj[key]));
}

// @run

[areAllEqual(array1, array2) , areAllEqual(array1, array3)]


// @benchmark Barmar

function objectsMatch(obj1, obj2) {
  const keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
  const keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);

  if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  // Iterate through the keys and compare their values
  for (const key of keys1) {
    if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // If all key-value pairs match, return true
  return true;
}

function compareArrays(a1, a2) {
  if (a1.length != a2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  return a1.every(el1 => {
    return a2.some(el2 => objectsMatch(el1, el2));
  });
}


// @run
[compareArrays(array1, array2), compareArrays(array1, array3)];


// @benchmark Alexander equal
const compare = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const map = {};
  for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    for(const k in arr1[i]){
      map[k] = arr1[i][k];
    }
  }
  for(let i=0;i < arr2.length;i++){
    const item = arr2[i];
    for(const k in item){
      if(map[k] !== item[k]){
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
// @run
[compare(array1, array2), compare(array1, array3)];

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```